# Why cannot Typescript unwrap this optional from generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Typescript version: 3.3.1

```
type Foo<T extends string> = {
    [key in T]: number | undefined;
};
function square(num: number) {
    return num * num;
}
function doStuff<T extends string>(foo: Foo<T>, keys: T[]) {
    return keys.map((key) => {
        const number = foo[key];
        return number && square(number);
            // TS2345: Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not
            // assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
            // Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    });
}
```

From the error message I see that typescript resolved the number to be `number | undefined`. Therefore I'd expect that Typescript will properly narrow the type to `number` in context of `number && ...`, but it does not. Why? Is there a way to simply fix it?

It works when I remove the generics and replace all `T`s with `string`s (and `[key: string]` instead of `[key in T]`) in the type.

Comment: You could refine with `typeof number === 'number' && ...` but still interesting why the original doesn't work

Comment: I guess this is a bug or a limitation of the ts compiler.. as a possible workaround you could use non-null assertion operator (!):  --> return number && square(number!)

Comment: The non-null assertion is what I ended with for now, but still this is dumb as obviously TS resolved the generics and knows at this moment number is `number|undefined`.